# touch AVCaptuerSession configuration while session is running

Tags: avfoundation, avcapturesession

From the Apple Documents, I didn't find somewhere clearly mentioned that while AVCaptuerSession is running, we could not do

```
[_AVCaptureSession beginConfiguration];
....
[_AVCaptureSession commitConfiguration];
```

I am wonderingif we touch AVCaptureSession configuration while session is running if it will cause some issue?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by touching AVCaptureSession configuration?